# React Apollo - Make Multiple Queries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I have a queries file that looks like this:

```
import {gql} from 'react-apollo';

const queries = {
  getApps: gql`
    {
      apps {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  `,
  getSubjects: gql`
    {
      subjects {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  `
};

export default queries;
```

I then import this file to my React component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import queries from './queries'

class Test extends Component {
...
}

export default graphql(queries.getSubjects)(graphql(queries.getApps)(Test));
```

This will only get data for one of the queries (getApps) and not both. If I do one at a time so that it looks like this:

```
export default graphql(queries.getSubjects)(Test);
```

then it works but I don't have my other query. Yes, I have tested both separately and they work. How do I get it so that both queries show up in my props.data?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

My preferred way is to use the `compose` functionality of the apollo client ([docu](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/higher-order-components.html#compose)).

EDIT:
If you have more than one query you should name them.

So in your case, it could look like this:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import queries from './queries'
import { graphql, compose } from 'react-apollo';

class Test extends Component {
...

  render() {
    ...
    
    console.log(this.props.subjectsQuery, this.props.appsQuery); // should show both 
    
    ...
  }
}

export default compose(
   graphql(queries.getSubjects, {
      name: "subjectsQuery"
   }),
   graphql(queries.getApps, {
      name: "appsQuery"
   }),
)(Test);
```

Comment: I did exactly this to no avail :(

Comment: Strange, did you try `console.log(this.props)` in the render function?

Comment: Yeah I tried that and only saw one of the properties I was expecting

Comment: I think i got the problem and edited the answer. Please let me know if it is working

Comment: This is working :) however, a little annoying that it all doesn't come under data (I use the loading property to show a spinner or not). I'll have to look into a batching solution. Have you worked with batching queries?

Comment: No i did not work with batching queries. Sounds interesting ;)

Comment: I get `graphql is not defined`

Comment: what happens with error and loading props all each query?

Comment: Error and loading props are found in the respective queries, e.g. this.props.appsQuery.error

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to reuse any of those queries independently, why not make a single request by combining both queries in one i.e:

```
const combinedQueries = gql`
{
  apps {
    id
    name
  }
  subjects {
    id
    name
  }
}
`
```

and then you can use it in your component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import combinedQueries from './combinedQueries'

class Test extends Component {
   ...
   render() {
     ...
     if(!this.props.combinedQueries.loading) {
       console.log(this.props.combinedQueries.apps);
       console.log(this.props.combinedQueries.subjects);
     }
     ...
   }
}

export default graphql(combinedQueries, {name: 'combinedQueries'})(Test);
```

Comment: what if one of them fails and the other does not? Can I retry them individually?

Answer (score 11):

IMHO, one of the most neat solutions is described in the [Apollo Client React implementation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/react-apollo-migration.html#compose-to-render-composition).
The basic idea is to wrap your queries into nested Query components. Using closure functions as component children makes it handy to delegate the results of one query down into another query and so on.

```
 const QueryOne = gql`
  query One {
    one
  }
`;

const QueryTwo = gql`
  query Two {
    two
  }
`;

const NumbersWithData = () => (
  <Query query={QueryOne}>
    {({ loading: loadingOne, data: { one } }) => (
      <Query query={QueryTwo}>
        {({ loading: loadingTwo, data: { two }}) => {
          if (loadingOne || loadingTwo) return <span>loading...</span>
          return <h3>{one} is less than {two}</h3>
        }}
      </Query>
    )}
  </Query>
);
```

Comment: I don't get the downvote on this as [1] describes that these nested `<Query>…</Query>` structure will be the result of using `compose`. And so it may be justified to use it in cases where `compose` appears unwieldy or you just don't want to build another component.

[1]: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/react-apollo-migration.html#compose-to-render-composition

Comment: note this _looks_ like QueryTwo will run only after QueryOne returns, but note that QueryTwo is not waiting for loadingOne to turn false, so they will in fact run in parallel. Unless you want to use QueryOne results as parameters to QueryTwo, in that case you can wait for loadingOne before rendering QueryTwo

Comment: I don't agree that this is 'neat', it looks like a nested-render-props-hell in the making.

Comment: I do agree that this is neat because it lets you build composable components with their own queries.  For example, you can have a parent component that handles paging lists of categories.  It can be agnostic about which children get rendered.  So, you can have a screen that lists authors and renders the author details for each author.  The first component queries authors and the second author details.  You can use the same top component to query articles and a different one to query article details as a child.  It's really very tidy!  However, evidently, it is hard to have one loading status.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using [react-adopt](https://github.com/pedronauck/react-adopt) to make this. It's really simple and keep our code clean.

Simple example:

```
import { adopt } from 'react-adopt';

...
render() {
  const Composed = adopt({
    first: ({ render }) => <Query query={FIRST_QUERY}>{ render }</Query>,
    second: ({ render }) => <Query query={SECOND_QUERY}>{ render }</Query>
  });

  return (
    <Composed>
      ({ first, second }) => {
        console.log('first', first)
        console.log('second', second)

        // validations (loading, error)

        return (
          <div>Your JSX</div>
        )
      }
    </Composed>
  )
}
...
```

There are a lot of examples using

```
const Composed = adopt({
  first: <Query query={FIRST_QUERY} />,
  second: <Query query={SECOND_QUERY} />
});
```

Be careful with `<Query>` component, It needs a children, otherwise, it will have the following error:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop children is marked as required in Query, but its value is undefined.
```

To avoid the previous warning, I have found a possible solution:

```
first: ({ render }) => <Query query={FIRST_QUERY}>{ render }</Query>
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: It would be a lot better to understand if you applied the Query components rather than just console.log them IMO.

Answer (score 5):

For **Apollo 2.x**: you can use `react-adopt` to compose the Queries and Mutations into a single level.  (That lib will compose any components with render props, e.g. the React Context API.)

https://github.com/pedronauck/react-adopt

Comment: I've found that the refetch doesn't update UI using adpot :/

Comment: Same issue here in regards to `refetch()`, any work arounds with `react-adopt` on refetching @JamieHutber?

Comment: Ye, I could write it up if you require. But in essence, the query exposes a `refetch` method which you can retain until you do your mutation. Still let me know I'll add an answer to this site.

Comment: @JamieHutber if you would post that I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 5):

The Emergence of Apollo Client useQuery Hooks; have changed everything. If you are reading this in 2020 or beyond; I am pretty much sure that you likely be using Apollo client useQuery hook. You can call useQuery Hook as many times as you want to execute the both queries. You can learn more about useQuery hooks in its official documentation https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/ I find it so useful in my recent project. E.g

```
const queries = {
  getApps: gql`
    {
      apps {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  `,

  getSubjects: gql`
    {
      subjects {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  `
};

const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(queries);

const { loading:getSubjectsLoading, error:getSubjectsError, data:getSubjects } = useQuery(getSubjects);

if (loading || getSubjectsLoading) return "Loading...";
if (error || getSubjectsError ) return <p>Error :(</p>;


console.log(data);
console.log(getSubjects);
```

Comment: Hey Emeka - as far as I can tell, this will still make multiple network POST calls to the graphql endpoint. Is this the same in your experience?

Comment: Yes; but that is what the question is all about. He want to make multiple queries. This will make multiple network calls to the graphql server.

Comment: Okay, yes, for some reason I though the OP was looking for a way do it using just one call. (that's what I was searching for). I guess the only way is to build a brand new query. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Link](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#compose), to use `compose()` you need to follow these steps:

1- install "recompose" package using `npm i recompose`

2- import package using `import { compose } from "recompose";`

3- use it in the form of:

```
export default compose(
  graphql(Query1, { alias: "Query1" }),
  graphql(Query2, { alias: "Query2" })
)(Test);
```

documentation : https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo/

Answer (score 0):

Another way around this is to use the `props` option.

```
export default compose(
  graphql(QUERY_2, {
    props: ({ data }) => ({ ...data }),
  }),
  graphql(QUERY_1, {
    props: ({ data }) => ({ ...data, myCustomAttribute: data.foo }),
  }),
)(Component);
```

I've found that this approach is a bit nicer for my use case.

Here is a link to the docs: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#graphql-config-props

Answer (score 0):

Since, compose has been removed from apollo, there's an alternative library called lodash. The method {flowRight} acts in the same way as compose.
Just follow the steps:-

1. npm i -s lodash
2. `import {flowRight} from 'lodash'`
3. Exchange the usage of compose with flowRight, all the other code will work the same.

Answer (score 0):

What about recursive React component?

```
export const QueriesExecutor = ({
    children,
    queries,
    variables,
    loading = false,
    ...rest
}) => {
    const lastQueryIndex = queries.length - 1;

    const {data, loading: _loading} = useQuery(
        queries[lastQueryIndex].query,
        {
            variables
        }
    );

    if (queries.length > 1) {
        return (
            <QueriesExecutor
                children={children}
                queries={queries.slice(0, lastQueryIndex)}
                variables={variables}
                loading={_loading}
                {...rest}
                {...data}
            />
        );
    }

    if (loading || _loading) return 'Loading...';

    return React.Children.only(
        React.cloneElement(children, {
            ...rest,
            ...data
        })
    );
};
```

- **queries**: an array of queries that you want to run in parallel
- **base case:** 1 query left, should render children
- **...rest**: used to collect query data from previous QueriesExecutor(s) until it reaches children

Answer (score -1):

```
  const { loading: cat_loading, cat_error, data: cat_data } = useQuery(categoriesAllQuery)
  const { loading: prod_loading, prod_error, data: prod_data } = useQuery(productsAllQuery)

  if (cat_loading || prod_loading) return <p>Loading ... </p>
  const { categoriesAll } = cat_data
  const { productsAll } = prod_data
```